# How can I redirect quickly while state routing?

Tags: angularjs, url, routes

While I click on link(http://domain.com/workspace) to redirect to controller workspaceController, the controller first executes all of its http requests and make current url and view to stay there till all requests complete for a seconds.

How can I redirect to the controller and load the view with some loading panel and http requests can be completed in the background?

//ws.module.js, module code start here for state routing

```
angular
    .module('app.workspace' ['appmodule'])
    .config(config);

function config($stateProvider) {
    $stateProvider.state('app.workspace', {
        url: '/workspace',
        views: {
            'content@app': {
                templateUrl: 'app/main/apps/workspace/workspace.html',
                controller: 'WorksapceController as vm'
            }
        }
    });
}
```

//ws.controller.js, controller code start here which initially call multiple functions(requests)

```
angular
    .module('app.workspace')
    .controller('WorksapceController', WorksapceController);

function WorksapceController($scope, $rootScope, $timeout, $location, $http, serverRequest, commonRequest) {
   loadListsitem();
   loadContacts();
   loadWS();
   function loadListsitem(){
        //http request 1
        //response bind to view using ng-repeat
   }
   function loadContacts(){
        //http request 2
        //response bind to view using ng-repeat
   }
   function loadWS(){
        //http request 3
        //response bind to view using ng-repeat
   }
}
```

Comment: Add your code as part of the question.

Comment: Please edit your question.